# how does one configure xdebug nginx and cloud9ide

Tags: cloud9-ide

its imp for me to get xdebug working with nginx and cloud 9 ide if I ever want to use cloud 9 ide.

I know the demo uses apache but we can't use that .

Answer (score 0):

As I know, c9.io uses php -S to debug (aka PHP Built-in).

Anyways, just configure nginx to run in c9.io (create a runner and so) and configure php-fpm with xdebug. It's not out of box, but I believe it's possible :)

Don't forget to *npm install debug* to make it work with c9 :)